# Printing a Tree/Trie using C++ Standard Libraries

Tags: c++, graphics, trie, suffix-tree, ascii-art

As part of a programming assignment, I've been asked to implement a suffix trie using C++. We are only allowed to implement this using [standard C++11 libraries](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/).

My implementation of the suffix trie consisted of a data structure `Trie(string T)`, which constructs a trie for a given string `s`. The functions in class `Trie` are the following:

- `Trie::Trie(string T)` - constructor: generates the trie.
- `Trie::substring(string s)` - boolean: checks whether a string `s` is a substring of `T`.
- `Trie::suffix(string s)` - boolean: checks whether a string `s` is a suffix to `T`.
- `Trie::count(string s)` - integer: returns the number of times a substring `s` appears throughout `T` (returns 0 if no `s` does not occur)
- `Trie::longestRepeat()` - string: finds the longest substring in `T` which occurs more than once.
- `Trie::longestSubstring(string S)` - string: finds the longest common substring shared by `S` and `T`

Other relevant information: The `Trie` data structure relies on two other data structures - `Node` and `Edge`. Each `Node` has a vector of `outgoing_edges` which point to other nodes.

---

How could I go about implementing an additional function, `Trie::show()` which generates a rendition of the trie? Since C++ has no inbuilt graphing libraries, I assume I'm forced to resort to some sort of ASCII-art type function. How could I go about building this, given the functions above?

Comment: Looks like an assignment?

Comment: @SharifMamun It is! I'm not looking for explicit solutions, only hints in the right direction.

Comment: If you show some attempt at a solution I think you are more likely to get help here.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy The thing is I don't know where to start :( I've already implemented all the functions listed above.

Comment: It sounds like you need to `#include <iomanip>` and then use a combination of `cout` or `printf`, `setprecision`, `setw`, ect to print your Trie, if you cannot use any 3rd party graphics libraries.